# MVVM solution for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here's the situtation:
`Data Context` of the window is: `MainViewModel`.

It's built from `ObservableCollections` of `SubViewModel.`
Each `SubViewModel` has its own `ObservableCollection` of type `String.`

Now, I have a treeview. The ItemsSource is the `ObservableCollection` of the `MainViewModel`.(Means it is the `SubViewModel` collection).

I want that if an item is selected, then there will be displayed the `ObservableCollection`(type String) of the `selected Item in the treeview.`

How can I do that?

Some code:

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TreeViewDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubViewModelCollection}"/>
```

I want to display the collection in a stack panel because of some reasons.
So: (TypeCollection is the string ObservableCollection of the item, it is currently not working of course)

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TypeCollection}" x:Name="UserList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateDataTemplate}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I've been struggling alot with that, how can I achieve my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the treeview `ItemsSource` to the `UserList`'s `SelectedItem`.

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TreeViewDataTemplate}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UserList Path=SelectedItem.SubViewModelCollection}"/>
```

Assuming the items in `UserList` are type `SubViewModel` which has an `IEnumerable<T>` property called `SubViewModelCollection`.

Comment: Ehm, it is not working, I don't even see the TreeView now. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/d3Fc0aNZ

Comment: The Items in UserList is an ObservableCollection inside the SubViewModel.

Comment: What do you mean you don't even see the treeview? There's nothing I've suggested that would make it disappear altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx), particularly the [portion pertaining to Event Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec8).  What this will allow you to do is publish an event in your application when an item in the TreeView is selected, consume that event elsewhere in your application and bind the ItemControl to the selected SubViewModel all without having to introduce any unnecessary coupling between these two pieces of your application.

Comment: An example would be nice :)

Comment: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/10/27/prism-and-silverlight-screencasts-on-channel-9.aspx